# ORMLite deleteDatabase is not deleting my databases

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Upon logout, I'm trying to drop all tables and then re create them when taken back to my LoginActivity.

I tried doing a `deleteDatabase` but this doesn't seem to be deleting the database at all because when I'm taken back to my LoginActivity, I can still query for the elements inside the database.

I'm trying to drop all tables from within my DrawerActivity when an `onClick` event is triggered. Here is what I have so far:

`DrawerAdapter.java`

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(getPosition() == 1) {
            context.deleteDatabase("mynew.db");
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class));      //end services here
        }
    }
```

Since the above is not working, I tried reading up on using the `TableUtils` to do my table dropping but I'm not sure if I'm supposed to be doing it this way inside my `DrawerAdapter`. If I am, how do I access those utilities from within the Adapter class? Then what's the next step when trying to recreate the tables that have been dropped?

Answer (score 1):

Your database will be deleted only if all the active connections are closed. So, ensure that you have no active connections and try again.

You need to call `SQLiteDatabase.close()` method on your database if you open it without closing it. Each `open()` requires a `close()`.

Comment: *"Each open() requires a close(), unless you use a singleton pattern and only one instance of your object exists."* That's not "unless" since each open still requires a close :)